# E-mail templates with mjml - blurred images

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, mjml

I'm currently working on some e-mail templates for my company using the mjml framework. Worked like a dream before I ran into some trouble with the images.

I set images like the company logo as .png files width 2x and resize them in the **mj-image** tag. In testing (gmail app on IOS) these images look blurry and I can't do nothing to prevent it.

Code is looking like this:

```
<mj-image width="261px" height="38px" src="***logo.png" padding-bottom="20px" href="#" alt=""></mj-image>
```

Anyone has some experience with this problem ?

Comment: So just to confirm, your png file is 2x the width (so, 522px wide?), and what you've specified in the `mj-image` tag is what you want the width to be? (That would be the normal way to cater for retina-quality / high-density screens)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need </mj-image>, see https://mjml.io/documentation/#mj-image

Comment: yes the image is 2x the size

Comment: Can you provide screenshot in gmail, and the original file?

Comment: Nothing against support here, but (FYI) there's great MJML support for questions just like this one at https://slack.mjml.io/.